# asp.net survey questionnaire engine

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, workflow, survey

I am looking to implement (or build as a last resort) a type of survey engine that allows for extensibility and integration into an existing workflow engine.

The survey/questionnaire engine should allow for admin users to add new questions and response types (text/bool/multiple/etc), should use SQL Server for persistence and ASP.NET 2.0 or greater.  It should leverage AD for Windows Integrated Auth and security.

Does anyone know of a good (free or cheap is even better) off-the shelf solution that meets these basic requirements?

Comment: try this http://surveymaster.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe these articles might be useful if you decide to build your own solution:

Web-Based Surveys Made Easy:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210513212537/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/061604-1.aspx

Working with the WebSurvey Control's Results:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210608183426/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111004-1.aspx

Comment: these 2 articles were written in 2004 and use .NET 1.1.  I am looking for a more recent product.  I found a commercial product called "Feedback Server" (www.nsurvey.com), which provides most (if not all) features I need...but it's kinda pricey.

Comment: That 4GuysFromRolla WebSurvey control can now be found here http://websurvey.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 9):

Try the C# open source Survey project (revived Nsurvey form engine and surveytool) at:

http://www.surveyproject.info (Demosite available and sources at Codeplex.com).

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Zodiac.NET Survey Engine](http://www.mentor-logic.com/index.php/products/components/zodiacnet) written in C# ASP.NET. It meets most of your requirement except it defines the questionnaire in XML format. It can persist the answers as XML files on the server. You can also save the answers to any database using its APIs and bind the XML on the fly to the web controls. The nice thing about this engine is that it's a collection of Web Controls. This is a great benefit when you want to integrate it with your existing applications.

Answer (score 1):

[SelectSurvey.Net](http://www.classapps.com/SelectSurveyNETOverview.asp) works well and has a lower cost than Feedback Server

Answer (score 1):

You can still find old NSurvey sources on the net ([here, e.g.](http://www.dotnetnukes.com/Members/NSurvey/tabid/81/language/en-US/Default.aspx)).

It's free, just don't get Feedback Server instead (now on nsurvey.org, unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

[Zodiac.NET](http://www.mentor-logic.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46:zodiac-net-web-aspnet-survey-engine-software&catid=34:components&Itemid=63) is another ASP.NET survey/questionnaire engine