# Dynamically creating ASP.NET form controls

Tags: asp.net, webforms, controls

I have a form which, based on the answers given in the prior page, can have about 10 different variations in the combination of fields (most are the same, but several change).  I decided rather than making 10 separate pages, I would try to make it dynamic.  Eventually this will pull the form setup from a database, but for now I'm just trying to get the dynamic part to work.  The following code kinda works, but it's giving me a weird result.

```
private void AddTestControls()
{
    var newbox = new TextBox();
    newbox.ID = "FirstBox";
    newbox.Text = "This is dynamic";
    newbox.CssClass = "stepHeader";
    DynamicDiv1.Controls.Add(newbox);

    var newlit = new Literal();
    newlit.ID = "FirstLit";
    newlit.Text = ".<br/>.";
    DynamicDiv1.Controls.Add(newlit);

    newbox.ID = "SecondBox";
    newbox.Text = "This is also dynamic";
    newbox.CssClass = "step";
    DynamicDiv1.Controls.Add(newbox);

}
```

I've stepped through it and all the properties are getting set correctly, but when the page finally renders, only the `SecondBox` control is visible.  There is no trace of the `FirstBox`.  If I change it so that `SecondBox` is its own object (`newebox2` for example) then both are visible, but with how I was thinking that I would ultimately do the form from the database, this could complicate things.  I don't understand why the textbox object has to be recreated in order to add it to the Div's collection of controls.  Am I going about this all wrong, or just missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "SecondBox" are overwriting the "FirstBox" `newbox` since it's still holding a reference to it. Create a new `TextBox` for the second box:

```
var newbox = new TextBox();
newbox.ID = "FirstBox";
newbox.Text = "This is dynamic";
newbox.CssClass = "stepHeader";
DynamicDiv1.Controls.Add(newbox);

var newlit = new Literal();
newlit.ID = "FirstLit";
newlit.Text = ".<br/>.";
DynamicDiv1.Controls.Add(newlit);

// Create a new TextBox
var secondBox = new TextBox();
secondBox.ID = "SecondBox";
secondBox.Text = "This is also dynamic";
secondBox.CssClass = "step";
DynamicDiv1.Controls.Add(secondBox);
```

I'm not quite sure why this could complicate things, but what you could do is create a method for creating a textbox, if that's easier:

```
TextBox CreateTextBox(string id, string text, string cssClass)
{
    var box = new TextBox();
    box.ID = id;
    box.Text = text;
    box.CssClass = cssClass;
    return box;
}
```

And then

```
var newBox = CreateTextBox("FirstBox", "This is dynamic", "stepHeader");
DynamicDiv1.Controls.Add(newBox);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I figured `.Add` meant creating a new object, not just passing a reference.  I'm not sure either why I thought it would complicate it... one of those things where you're planning it out in your mind and it just doesn't make sense.  I ended up shortening your method suggestion to something like `var newbox = new TextBox() {ID = "FirstBox" CssClass = "stepHeader" Text = "This is dynamic"}` since that shortens the amount of code and effects the same change.

Comment: @techturtle Happens to everybody =) I actually would write as you did, but for illustration purposes I wrote it as a method.

Answer (score 0):

What's how it suppose to work. `newbox1` is a reference so after the first time it's added to `DynamicDiv1`, it's there and if you change its `Text`, then the `Text` will be changed. You may find this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343068/asp-net-survey-questionnaire-engine) useful. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940007/saving-a-reference-to-a-int) demostrates the same issue you are having.